# If $K_1,...,K_n$ are compact convex sets then ${\bar conv}(K_1,...,K_n)= conv(K_1,...,K_n)$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is a locally convex space and $K_1,...,K_n$ are compact convex subsets of $X$, then ${\bar conv}(K_1,...,K_n)= conv(K_1,...,K_n)$ and this convex hull is compact.

Unfortunately I do not have any idea for it. Please hint me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $\bar{conv(K_1,\ldots,K_n)}$ mean the closure here, so you want to show that the convex hull is closed?

Comment: yes, I want to show that it is closed and compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that $$\mbox{conv}\left\{A\cup B\right\} =\{tu+sv :t,s\geq 0 , t+s =1 , u\in A , v\in B\}.$$ Then by induction show that $$\mbox{conv}\left\{\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j\right\} =\left\{\sum_{j=1}^n t_ju_j  :t_j\geq 0 , \sum_{j=1}^n t_j =1 , u_j\in A_j \right\}.$$
Then consider the $n-1$ dimensional simplex $S=\left\{ (t_1 ,t_2 ,..., t_n ): \sum_{j=1}^n t_j =1 , t_j\geq 0\right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and map $\sigma :S\times A_1 \times A_2 \times ...\times A_n \to X$ , $\sigma (t_1 ,..., t_n , u_1 ,..., u_n ) =\sum_{j=1}^n t_ju_j .$ The map is continous and the set $S\times A_1 \times A_2 \times ...\times A_n$ is compact hence the image $$\sigma (S\times A_1 \times A_2 \times ...\times A_n )$$ is compact but $$\sigma (S\times A_1 \times A_2 \times ...\times A_n ) =\mbox{conv}\left\{\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j\right\}.$$